# Calculating the reduced row echelon form to find the maximum set of linearly independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gram-schmidt

I calculated the reduced row of the following matrix:

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{X} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$$

And then I got the following matrix $$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{X} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}$$

But then I want to know what are my independent vectors (the maximum number of them ), so what shall I do? (I am given a set of vectors that are not linearly independent and I am trying to find the maximum set of linearly independent vectors of them to use them in Gram-Schmidt)

Comment: The linearly independent rows are simply the nonzero rows.. Note that the last form of $X$ is in row echelon form, but certainly not in *reduced* row echelon form.

Comment: Which vectors are you asking about? Are they the rows or the columns of your matrix?

Comment: they are the columns of my first matrix @amd

Comment: In that case here’s a hint: row-reduction preserves linear independence of the columns. It should be easy to pick out a set of independent columns in the reduced matrix.

Comment: @Bernard should it be in the RREF to find the maximum set of linearly independent vectors?

Comment: will they be the first, second and fourth? @amd

Comment: No. Any echelon form will do. The R.R.E.F. is useful to find the solutions with the augmented matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But then I want to know what are my independent vectors (the maximum number of them ), so what shall I do?

Well, since echelon form contains all-zeros in the last row, then the rank is $4 - 1 = 3$, then to extract the linearly independent vectors, just take the first three rows. Actually, any combination of $3$ rows would do ;)

Comment: Ohh why your last statement is correct?

Comment: But the OP  plugged the given vectors vertically  ( as I know this problem) can she take the horizontal ones ? It seems like the third column is not linearly independent from the first 2. Does this means that the RREF is not correct?